# Backwards masking in music

Tags: psychology, music, backmasking

It was alleged by opponents to rock and heavy metal that the artists would include hidden satanic messages in their songs that would become audible when playing the song backwards.

It was further claimed that the brain would still be able to subconsciously decode the message and thus manipulate the person in a subliminal way.

I know that the pattern-seeking behavior of our brain will make us hear things that are not there, such as whispering voices in the wind, or voices in white noise. Thus, a plausible explanation of the backwards messages is that the brain makes these things up when listening to something that sounds like spoken words, as spoken words backwards clearly are.

This is, however, still not prove that nobody deliberately put backwards messages into music. Thus my question:

**Is there conclusive evidence that subliminal messages (i.e. reversing audio) has
been attempted in rock or heavy metal
music?**

Comment: Wikipedia has a list of songs with backmasked messages:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backmasked_messages

Comment: I played in a published metal band and we put backward messages more than once. It's like an easter egg in software! I am not putting links to avoid being spammy...

Comment: @Oliver_C The list, however, does not prove that these were intentionally included.

Comment: @Lagerbaer - No, not all of them. There are however some songs where the backmasking was intentional, mostly as an easter egg or to poke fun at the backmasking controversy, like Weird Al Yankovic's "Satan eats Cheez Whiz". Wiki does provide references.

Comment: Is it then safe to say that intentional backmasking started only after it was raised as a controversy?

Comment: !lacitpeks eb !lacitpeks eb

Comment: subliminal messages != reversing audio

Comment: Styx put a backwards message before their song ["Heavy Metal Poisoning"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_Metal_Poisoning) on the "Kilroy was Here".  It is quite obvious and was intentional, although in Latin.  It makes no sense when the album is played forward, IMHO.

Comment: Michael Shermer has a [fantastic example of backward masking and priming](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eju9mm6eCa4&t=1m10s) via Led Zeppelin's Stairway to Heaven.

Comment: It is/has definitely been used a lot. If it was used first to hide messages just in an easter-egg like manner or was used for 'shock value' after the allegations of some fundamental groups seems to be uncertain. However it has been proven that such messages, if deliberately inserted to manipulate thoughts of people, would not work that way. The interesting question would be who started first.

Comment: Kravallsubban Lever even has a track named "nataS roF flesruoY lliK", but like many other cases of backmasking it was probably put there as a joke.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that the pattern-seeking behavior of our brain will make us hear things that are not there, such as whispering voices in the wind, or voices in white noise. Thus, a plausible explanation of the backwards messages is that the brain makes these things up when listening to something that sounds like spoken words, as spoken words backwards clearly are.

You are pretty much correct with this, the official term is [Pareidolia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradolia) where the human brain makes out patterns where there really are none. There was an interesting [Skeptoid episode](http://skeptoid.com/episodes/4105) about this and it appears most of the proof supporting the claim of the existence of back masking is carefully cherry picked and edited sections of songs.